# Noun for a person with wrong moral values

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an individual who has wrong moral values? I was thinking about "hypocrite", but I'm not sure.

I'm looking for a noun, rather than an adjective. It may also be informal and shouldn't be too strong or too insulting. Imagine a teenager, who is still adjusting his principles and values.

Comment: By *wrong* do you mean 'differing from my own'? If so, be aware that the word will also be used by others to describe you.

Comment: I don't mean 'differing from my own', but rather unethical.

Comment: "Hypocrite" would only work to describe a person who "**acts** in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings" (morals), but whether his/her beliefs/feelings/morals are considered to be 'right' or 'wrong' would be irrelevant. Your mention of "unethical" might work, as might "immoral."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Unprincipled:

```
 Unprincipled: not having or showing concern for what is right
```

(Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

Or Nefarious:

```
Nefarious: flagrantly wicked or impious
```

(Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

**EDIT**:

For a noun, what about Rogue:

```
Rogue a man who is dishonest or immoral
```

Okay, what about Rascal? I personally don't think this is too negative:

```
Rascal: a person and especially a young person who causes trouble or does things that annoy people
```

Comment: 'Unprincipled' is the adjective, but I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: Another one I do not feel like adding a definition to is scoundrel

Comment: Rogue sounds too strong.

Comment: Then what about Rascal?

Answer (score 0):

If, as the OP has said in a comment, the adjective is *unprincipled* then the noun is ***reprobate*** or one of its synonyms.

A ***reprobate*** is an *unprincipled person*, according to Oxford Dictionaries Online.

However, I am not clear that *unprincipled* is the same thing as having *wrong moral values*. *Unprincipled* suggests no moral values at all.

So the question, taken with the comment seems slightly ambiguous. But a ***reprobate*** is an unprincipled person.

Answer (score -1):

[**"immoral"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immoral) applies perfectly to someone who has wrong moral values.

> - not morally good or right : morally evil or wrong, conflicting with generally or traditionally held moral principles  (The Free Dictionary)

Edit: Oh, you are asking for a noun?  I suggest **"knave"** or **"scoundrel"**

Comment: I'm looking for a noun. May also be informal.

Answer (score -1):

Consider, ***scalawag***

> : a usually young person who causes trouble : ***scamp***; reprobate [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scalawag)